# Plotting previous PDH Higher than Current

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

[Consecutive Higher PD Highs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOdWp.png)
I am trying to plot previous day high(PDH) and subsequent prior day's highs which are higher than current DH. The script attached is plotting all PDH/PDL. How to eliminate the highs lower than the current Day High?

```
//@version=2
study(title="Pre-PDH.PDL", shorttitle="Pre-PDH.PDL", overlay=true)

//Previous High,Low,Close
pdc = security(tickerid, 'D', close[1])
pdh = security(tickerid, 'D', high[1])
pdl = security(tickerid, 'D', low[1])


//Colour
highcolour=pdh != pdh[1] ? na : red
lowcolour=pdl != pdl[1] ? na : green
closecolour=pdc != pdc[1] ? na : blue

//Plots on all days  
offs_daily = 0 

closeplot=plot(pdc, title="Prev Close", style=line, linewidth=1, color=closecolour)
plot(pdh, title="Prev High", style=line, linewidth=2, color=highcolour)
plot(pdl, title="Prev Low", style=line, linewidth=2, color=lowcolour)
```